# When using Python 3.4 I get error no module "requests"

Tags: python, import, pip, python-requests

I was developing a basic web crawler and wanted to use 'import requests' in my code. This throws an error. I am using pycharm and it is not able to work there.

I searched around on Google and saw many people have the same issues. I tried following their solutions and still couldn't figure it out. I tried downloading `pip`, `pip3`, `pip3.4` using the Windows 10 `cmd` but I couldn't get the problem to go. Even after installing these packages, I am getting the same error.

Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paras/PycharmProjects/Monty/First.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Installing `pip` or `pip3` won't fix the issue, it just gives you a means to fix the issue. `pip3 install requests` - does that work?

Comment: it didnt work still getting the same error.

Comment: You haven't actually included the error. I have edited out the code since your error is apparently from `import requests` so the rest of the code is irrelevant (and was not correctly formatted). However, you should include the full traceback.

Comment: Are you using virtual enviroment?

Comment: how do i use virtual environment on pycharm? @Joozty